# Route change after login not working with Angular js, ui-router, satellizer and IE 11

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

In Chrome, Firefox, and Opera when the user logs in the app redirects to 'dash' state. But in IE 11 it successfully logs in, redirects to 'dash' state then immediately back to 'login' state.

Parts of index:

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

....

```
    <div ui-view></div>
```

Part of app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'monospaced.elastic', 'satellizer', 'slick', 'chart.js', 'wu.masonry', 'ngSanitize']);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login', 
        templateUrl: '../login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    })
    .state('dash', {
        url: '/dashboard', 
        templateUrl: '../dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DashboardController'
    })
    .state('home', {
        url: '/', 
        templateUrl: '../home.html'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

This is login.js:

```
app.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $state, $auth, $http, $rootScope) {
    $scope.login = function(user) {
        $scope.showError = false;       
        $scope.showValidationError = false;
        $scope.showRateError = false;
        $scope.showNoUserError = false;
        if(angular.isUndefined(user)) {
            $scope.showValidationError = true;
        }
        console.log("do login");
        $auth.login({
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password
        }).then(function(response) {
            $auth.setToken(response);
            console.log("login success");
            $state.go('dash');
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("login error " + error.data.message + " " + error.status);
            if(error.status === 401) {
                $scope.showError = true;
            }
            if(error.status === 403) {
                $scope.showRateError = true;
            }
            if(error.status === 422) {
                $scope.showValidationError = false;         
            }
            if(error.status === 500) {
                $scope.showNoUserError = true;
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Part of dash.js:

```
    $http({
        method: 'GET', 
        url: '/api/project/', 
        headers: { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage.satellizer_token }
    }).then(function(response){
        $scope.projects = response.data;
        $scope.$broadcast('controllerUpdate', $scope.projects);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        if(response.status === 401) {
            $state.go('login');
        }
    });
```

Seems like it logs in successfully, goes to 'dash' but then when it tries a 'get' request from dash it fails due to authorization...

Update

Now it's getting to dash sometimes, but sometimes the project data doesn't load. Not sure what the problem is :/ Is it a timing issue? And why doesn't it happen in other browsers?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you getting this  console.log("login success"); message??

Comment: Yes it's printing do login then login success

Comment: is it working properly in other browsers??

Comment: Working in Firefox, Opera and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out IE doesn't like trailing slashes...

Doing a get on url: '/api/project/', was returning a 401 error but only from IE and it was redirecting to 'login'.